# Is there an img (javascript) equivalent to background-size:cover?

Tags: image, css

I'm working on a responsive design that showcases photos in a grid. The photos themselves can be in all aspect ratios and sizes. Furthermore, the grid cells in which they are placed are also not of a fixed width, they scale as you resize the browser. Further, each grid cell, although dynamic in width and height, is of the same size, regardless of the image inside it.

To properly show photos in this highly dynamic situation, I have found a working recipe: each photo is basically a div with the image set as the background image. To properly scale the unknown width/height of the image inside a dynamically sized grid, I'm making use of CSS3's background-size:cover feature.

The end result is fabulous, it does exactly what I want in terms of UI and display. Still, I'm not pleased with the reduced accessibility of this solution: it's not SEO friendly and not plugin friendly (think of social plugins). Therefore, I'm trying to reproduce the working situation I have but this time using good old img tags instead of CSS backgrounds.

I know there are IE8 and below polyfills for background-size:cover, but I'm not looking for that, I'm looking for a solution based on img tags. I also found articles using absolute positioning techniques as well as CSS's clip property, but keep in mind nothing about my design is absolute in size.

I guess what I'm looking for is a javascript routine that has the logic of background-size:cover for dynamic sizing, in a situation where both the source (image dimensions) and target (display box) are dynamic in size.

**Is there such a javascript equivalent to background-size:cover that works on img tags?**

Comment: you should be able to use width:100% or height:100% to get most of the effect of background-size:cover. It might not work when you have a mix of very different aspect ratios though.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks, I have added one extra requirement to my answer: each grid cell is of the same size, a dynamic size based on window width. Setting one dimension to 100% will partly do the job, but it does not center the image like "cover" does.

Comment: Would simply setting "img { max-width: 100%; }" maybe not do what you're looking for?

Comment: @BillyMoat It solves one part of the problem, but not the centering part that background-size:cover realizes.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing your problem or a link to your site?

Answer (score 4):

This is old, but I recently found a novel solution.

Instead of making the img you want to display the background image of a div, create an image:

```
<div>
    <img src="mypic.jpg"/>
</div>
<style>
    div {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
    img {
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background: url(mypic.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size:cover;
        padding:50%;
    }
</style>
```

Set a containing div to be the width/height you want the image.  Then put the image inside as 100% width/height and set the src to the img you want.  Also set the img you want as the background image of the img.  Set the background-size to cover, and the padding at 50%.

The trick is the padding at 50%.  The img width/height is fixed, so as you increase the padding, the image gets smaller and smaller.  50% is exactly how much is needed for it to be hidden, and now you just see the background image of the image displayed how you want, but it's still accessible!

http://jsfiddle.net/t72xgbw0/

Comment: if we had support got `attr` it would have been so much easier. please vote - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435426

Comment: This solution doesn't completely satisfy the criteria as asked. The background image of the img tag will be blocked by the src image of the img tag, the displayed output is an image that is stretched.

Comment: It does work, and the src image of the image tag isn't visible, as explained in the answer by using the padding.
It's possible your defaults have different box sizing.  I've updated the answer and included a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking of accesibility and SEO, I created a solution to a very similar problem using jQuery, it doesn't reproduce the logic of background cover, it makes use of it.

The images in fact become the role of the container with the background and the background cover gets added programatically.

```
$imagesContainer.find('img').each(function(i, elem){
  $(elem).css({
    backgroundSize : 'cover',
    backgroundImage : 'url("' + $(elem).attr('src') + '")',
    backgroundPosition : 'center',
    display : 'block',
    height : '100%', // Or any size needed.
    width : '100%'
  });
  $(elem).removeAttr('src');
});
```

Comment: I actually like the overall concept of this solution. It degrades gracefully for accessibility or search-agent situations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way to cover a container with an image using css and javascript:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;   // To cover container
  min-height: 100%;  // To cover container
  top: 50%;          // To move image corner to center of container
  left: 50%;         // To move image corner to center of container
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('img').css({
  'margin-top': -$('img').height()/2,   // To move to center of image
  'margin-left': -$('img').width()/2    // To move to center of image
});
```

Make sure to run the javascript after image has loaded.

Comment: Noticed that this works only if the image is smaller than its container :(

Answer (score -1):

I believe there are two things you want to do:

1. Have an image fill the window
2. Make sure the image is centered vertically and horizontally.

The trouble is (if you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image) is that you have to both center it vertically and horizontally depending on the image and browser size.

You can make a pure CSS solution using a combination of `display:table` and `margin:0 auto`, along with smart height/width settings.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yVYM/3/

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: This isn't at all how `backgound-size:cover` behaves.